# c++ struct pointer with parameters

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class BST {
    
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* t) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

Although I did not post the entire code, I believe it is enough for my question.
My only question is "node* makeEmpty(node* t)"

What is this?

I know a function has a return type which is constructed as follow in a generic way.

```
return_type function_name(... parameters ...){

}
```

return type can be void, int, double, long long, char, what ever it is. But I am not getting "node* makeEmpty(node* t)" this code right here.

node is a class (struct) that has int, and two pointers.

something that can connects me here is, I can create a pointer object of node class as follow

```
node* root
node* root = new node;
node* root = new node();
```

Something similar with those initialization of a class pointer.

but with "node* makeEmpty(node* t)" this? my best guess is a node* class pointer with a function or something.

### Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking what `node*` means?

Comment: return type can be whatever, it can also be a pointer to a `node`, `node*` is a pointer to a `node`

Comment: The function returns a pointer to `node*`, which actually is `nullptr` anyway. Doesn't appear meaningful, would rather prefer a `void` return type in this specific case. Side note: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: @Aconcagua well I pull this code up from GitHub. so Im just trying to see what am I missing. and yes I definitely agree we should use nullptr instead of NULL. What do you mean by "function returns a pointer to node*"? are you referring to the node* as a class or the null will be returned to whatever it is being called?

Comment: Typo of mine, sorry. `node*` is a pointer to `node`. Actually, pointer to `node*` is possible, too, but that's a `node**`.

Comment: @Aconcagua well in this case, I would do node* makeEmpty(node* &t) instead. double ** is so annoying. I'm guessing node* makeEmpty(node* t) is simply granting the access right to makeEmpty so that it can go thru the right left values otherwise, I guess it will not able to read or go thru the left sub tree and right sub tree. thats my intuition.

Comment: @JeffreyStewart `*&` often is preferable. But sometimes you might need to re-assign the pointer to pointer, too, which cannot be accomplished with references...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the `constructor` for the `node`.
Here's an example that will initialize:

```
struct node
{
    // Default constructor
    node()
    : data(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr)
    { ; }

    // Data constructor
    node(int new_data)
    : data(new_data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr)
    { ; }

    int data;
    node * left;
    node * right;
};
```

In the above example, I've provided a default constructor and a *data* constructor.  Each version sets the links to null.

Comment: im not sure if it is a constructor, but the class is BST and there is another strcut call node. Im confused with "node* makeEmpty(node* t)" why I need to use the same name with the struct class that I have? node* is a class (struct) pointer, and makeEmpty is the function name. so I am not able to retrieve any info from the book that talks about this specific syntax. so I am confused. if node* becomes void. well I do understand what is going on

Comment: @JeffreyStewart, Please clarify.  I provided constructor information for the inner class.  The BST has many pointers to the `node` class.  My understanding of the OP's question, is how to initialize the targets of the pointers, namely `node` instances.

Comment: I would not use nested classes or structs.  It causes more code, makes the program more complex and doesn't allow sharing of the `node` class (actually, it's easier to share when the `node` is outside the `BST` class, in its own headers and source).

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes I agree. the code is from GitHub. I just have no clue what does "node* makeEmpty(node* t)" do. makeEmpty is a function name with (node* t) parameter. node* is a class pointer. Thats all I know. a side question, in production, do we always put everything in a class?